# Binding values from function to global environment in R

Tags: r, environments

I'm having trouble understanding how to bind values from within a function to an environment outside of the function. A basic example is shown below, I cannot seem to solve the last part of the function:

```
number <- data.frame()

how_many_fruits <- function() {

    answer <- as.integer(readline(prompt="How Many?: "))
    globalenv()$number <- rbind(globalenv()$number, answer)

}
```

Essentially, I want to have an empty data frame called `number` in the beginning, and every time `how_many_fruits()` is run, I want the input to be attached to the bottom of the `number` data frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `<<-` operator:

```
number <- data.frame()
how_many_fruits <- function() {

  answer <- as.integer(readline(prompt="How Many?: "))  
  number <<- rbind(number, answer)

}
```

However, I wonder what your goal is with that procedure. A function should not use variables in the global environment in the way you do. What will happen, if someone wants to use that function, but calls the variable `num` instead of `number`? The function won't work in that situation. So I would suggest that you do the following instead:

```
how_many_fruits <- function(num) {

  answer <- as.integer(readline(prompt="How Many?: "))
  new_num <- rbind(num, answer)

  return (new_num)
}

number <- data.frame()
number <- how_many_fruits(number)
```

This is how a function is supposed to work: it takes inputs (here called `num`) and it returns an output (here called `new_num`). Note how the name of the input and output *inside* the function need not be the same as the name of the variables you use *outside* the function. When you call `how_many_fruits(number)`, the contents of `number` are stored in `num` and the function only works with the latter. And when you do `number <- how_many_fruits(number)`, whatever is returned as the result of `how_many_fruits(number)` is stored in `number`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the alternative method! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to modify the global environment directly from within a function. Usually it is a better idea just to return a value and let the user append it to where's necessary. (Just as Stibu explained).

However, what you can also do is to use nested environments like in the following modification of an example from the official R language definition:

```
fruitscollector <- function(){
  fruitslist <- NULL
  function(){
    answer <- as.integer(readline(prompt="How Many?: "))
    fruitslist <<- c(fruitslist, answer)
    fruitslist
  }
}
```

So when you first initialize a "fruitscollector" it returns just a function that can collect values.

```
foo <- fruitscollector()
```

Now every time you use `foo`, a value will be added to the collection (and the whole collection is returned):

```
foo()
foo()
# etc
```

`fruitslist` is stored in the parent environment of  `foo`, so not in the global environment where you can accidentally delete it.

### edit

A more general idea would be to create an object (somewhat similar to what is called an "object" in OOP) with functions as methods, e.g.

```
collector <- function(){
  stack <- NULL
  list(
    add = function(x) stack<<-c(stack, x),
    get = function() stack,
    empty = function() stack <<- NULL
  )
}
```

Now the `add` method will add to the stack, `get` method will return the whole stack, and `empty` method will empty it.

```
foo <- collector()  # initialize
foo$get()  # NULL
foo$add(1)  # add 1 to the stack
foo$get()  # 1
foo$add(3)  # add 3 to the stack
foo$get()  # 1 3
foo$add(1:5) # etc...
```

Comment: a more formal explanation of how it works (and R scoping rules): https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf p 24-25

Comment: Thanks mate, I appreciate the further explanations and examples!